# static_cast const reference to void*

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I have a const reference to a void*:

```
void* p;
void* const& x = p;
```

I'd like to cast it to a const reference to a T* (for some `struct T {};`). Of the three ways I can think of doing this, my default choice of `static_cast` doesn't work:

```
T* const& y = static_cast<T* const&>(x);       // doesn't work
T* const& y = reinterpret_cast<T* const&>(x);  // works
T* const& y = (T* const&) x;                   // works
```

GCC gives the following error:

```
error: invalid static_cast from type ‘void* const’ to type ‘T* const&’
       T* const& y = static_cast<T* const&>(x);
```

I'd like to understand what it means, and if there is a way to fix it.

---

### EDIT (2019-11-26):

There is a discussion in the comments and answers about whether `T* const&` (and `void* const&`) is

1. a const reference to `T*`; or
2. a reference to `const T*`.

The consensus in the comments seems to be that it's option 2. But from the following example, it seems to me that it's option 1.

Suppose I have a class `T` with a non-const function `f()`:

```
struct T
{
  void f() {};  // NB: non-const
};
```

We can consider two options:

```
const T*  x;
T* const& y;
```

Calling `f()` via them produces different effects:

```
x->f();   // compile-time error (passing ‘const T’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers)
y->f();   // works fine
```

Does this not suggest that option 1 is correct? Can somebody reconcile this for me?

Comment: given that a reference once bound can't be changed why do you want to qualify it with a const? A reference to a const makes sense but Isn't a const reference superfluous?

Comment: I don't want `p` to be modifiable through `x` or `y`, but I do want `p` to be modifiable and changes visible in `x` and `y`.

Comment: @pcodex The reference is not `const`. @OP is just being imprecise. In English they've said "`const` reference to pointer to `void`", but what they mean is "reference to `const` pointer to `void`", which is what the code says.

Comment: @HTNW Wait a second. That was not my intention. Perhaps, I got it wrong. What I actually want is a const reference to void*. How do I express that in code?

Comment: Maybe functionally there is not a difference between the two, and that's what @pcodex means?

Comment: @HTNW is correct.  so the const is bound to the pointer. You are referring to a constant pointer. The error message gives a clue. The cast fails because you are trying to static cast from a const pointer to a reference to a const pointer. The reinterpret cast succeeds because it assumes you know what you are doing making it dangerous.

Comment: @foxcub you don't need to express a const reference explicitly. Once initialised a reference cannot be changed so it is implicitly a const reference. What you have declared in your code is sufficient.

Comment: so if you don't want p to be modifiable via x or y you should declare p as void* const p = some address

Comment: @pcodex But I want p to be modifiable directly. If I declared `const void* p`, then I cannot change `p`, which I want to be able to do, just not through `x` or `y`. I guess if the reference is to a const pointer, I cannot modify the target, which is good enough for my purposes, but if it were `void*&` or something like that, then `p` could be modified through `x` or `y`, which I don't want.

Comment: as i said earlier the problem is only with the cast. This worked for me:
        void*  p;
 void* const &x = p;
 int* const &y = static_cast<int* const>(x);
I've not used a templated version though.

Comment: @foxcub: `const void*` is not const-qualified; its referent (of unspecified type) is.  `void *const p;` would prevent modifying `p` but not (after appropriate casting) the object to which it points.

Comment: @pcodex Ah, I understand. Thanks!

Comment: @DavisHerring Thanks, I'm aware of this.

Comment: @pcodex I've modified my question to add a question about const reference vs reference to const. Can you comment on that?

Comment: Please do not edit a question to substantially change it -- if you have a new question then post a new Question; or you can use comments under an Answer to request clarification. I would suggest rolling back the question to the original .

Comment: @M.M Well, the edit goes to the heart of my question. there is a lot of disagreement in the comments, with everyone before your comment to an answer below implying that it's option 2, rather than option 1. I feel that the Edit clarifies my question, although I clearly should have phrased it better in the first place.

Comment: y->f() works since y is a const pointer to a non-const object and f() is a non-const function

Comment: going back to your original question if you don't want 'p' to be modifiable by 'x' then declare x to be a pointer to constant. Take a look at my answer below. However I've used pointers.

Comment: I want `*x`, well really `*y`, to be modifiable. I don't want `p` itself -- the address stored in `p` -- to be modifiable through `y`; I do want it to be modifiable by changing `p` directly, and I want the changes to be reflected in `y`.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t bind a reference to any other type (except a less cv-qualified version of the same type or certain subtle things involving reading individual bytes via special types like `unsigned char&`).  If you force the matter with a `reinterpret_cast` (including via a C-style cast), it’s undefined behavior to *use* the result (other than by casting it back).

You can (with merely `static_cast`) convert a `void*` *value* to `T*`, and you can make conveniences like

```
const auto y=[&] {return static_cast<T*>(p);};
```

so that you can track `p`’s current value by writing `y()` anywhere later.  (Since it returns by value, you indeed can’t write `y()=new T`, as desired.)

Comment: This doesn't really work for me. I want to pass `p` as a `T*` argument to a function, but I want that argument be passed by reference, i.e., if `p` changes, the argument should change "on-the-fly". It's a nice trick you are describing, but it doesn't quite work for me.

Comment: @foxcub it would be good to add that requirement to the question . But this answer is still the appropriate answer, `y()` will reflect the updated value of `p` .

Comment: @M.M Well, so would reinterpret_cast. The original question was about why static_cast doesn't work, not how to create an alternative solution.

Comment: @foxcub: But `reinterpret_cast` **doesn’t work**.  If you want to pass a `T* const&` that references the `void*`, the answer is simply that you can’t.  It’s not that this is unimplementable, but supporting it would be harmful to optimization (and would be inconsistent with other similar cases), and the committee has not seen fit to allow it for that reason.

Comment: @DavisHerring In what sense does it not? It works as intended with both GCC and Clang. I feel like I'm missing what you are saying here.

Comment: I hope it's implicit in everything I say that `p` would only point to objects of type `T`. Otherwise, of course, none of this makes sense.

Comment: @foxcub3: As always, undefined behavior is undefined.  It can be **anything**, including what you (naïvely) hoped to have happen.  With a new compiler version, a new optimization option, or an apparently unrelated change to the code, you may discover a rather less desirable result.  (And it’s still undefined even with the (reasonable!) restriction to pointing to objects of type `T`.)

Comment: @DavisHerring: How do you know it's undefined behavior? Which part of the standard are you referring to?

Comment: @DavisHerring: Also, is C-style cast also UB?

Comment: @foxcub:See [basic.lval/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11).  I addressed the C-style cast in my answer, but it’s [expr.cast/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cast#4.sentence-2).

Comment: @DavisHerring: I don't understand why that applies. `p` will only store pointers to objects of type `T`. It's certainly legal to assign it back to pointers to `T` (what your solution essentially does). Why is it illegal to do this with references? (Or I guess equivalently with pointers to pointers? Something like `void**` to `T**`.)

Comment: @foxcub: You can’t access (read **or** write) a `V` via a `U&`; here `V` is `void*` and `U` is `T*`.  The fact that you can convert a *value* of type `U` to `V` or vice versa (as my lambda does) is irrelevant, just like it would be for `V` of `int` and `U` of `long`—even when those hold all the same values (*e.g.*, on Windows).

Comment: @DavisHerring: I see. Thanks for the explanation. It seems like an artificial restriction for pointers, but at least I now understand what you mean.

Comment: @foxcub: As I said, it’s for optimization (the general name is TBAA).  Otherwise, the compiler would have to conservatively reload an `A*` from memory after *every* store to *any* `B*` just in case they happened to alias (except where the address *of* one of the pointers was known not to have escaped).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your original problem of not wanting to modify a value via a certain pointer the following should work. Templating it should give the same result. Bring in references if you need to but it will have the same result.

```
void myfunc1(int* intptr)
{
    (*intptr)++;
    std::cout << "In myfunc1 "<< *intptr<<"\n";
}

void myfunc2(const int* intptr)
{
    //(*intptr)++; //modification not possible
    std::cout << "In myfunc2 " << *intptr << "\n";
}

int main()
{       
    int* val = new int;
    *val = 32;

    void*  p = val; 

    std::cout << "Before myfunc1 " << *val << "\n";
    myfunc1(static_cast<int*>(p));
    std::cout << "After myfunc1 "<<*val<<"\n";

    //no modification via pointer to const
    const int* x = static_cast<const int*>(p);
    myfunc2(x);
    std::cout << "After myfunc2 " << *val << "\n";
```

Comment: I'm not sure what this is meant to demonstrate or what it has to do with my problem. I want the pointee to be modifiable (e.g., its non-const functions callable). I just want the reference itself to be const, so the contents of the pointer (the actual address assigned to the variable) cannot be changed.

Comment: you don't need the reference to be const, only that it should refer to a const to achieve what you are seeking. My code above demonstrates this distinction, it just uses pointers instead. I'll add some code using references later today